# Any way to set up multiple independent VPNs with OpenVPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Looking to find some way to set up multiple VPNs under a single OpenVPN Server, where external clients can only connect to other devices in the same network/group.

```
Open VPN Server (host)
    VPN Group 1 (10.0.10.x)
        -> Andy
        -> Bob
        -> Chloe
    VPN Group 2 (10.0.11.x)
        -> Dave
        -> Emma
    VPN Group 3 (...)
```

So in this example, Andy/Bob/Chloe are on one private network and can connect to each other, but *cannot* connect to Dave/Emma. In the same way, Dave/Emma can connect to each other, but not Andy/Bob/Chloe.

Is this possible? I couldn't find any examples in the OpenVPN docs...

Comment: Which system/distribution are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu Server 12.04

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem at all. You can launch several server instances using different port and daemon name config options

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail to this answer. How would the OP go about achieving what you suggested? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on the system and/or distribution he's using. In Debian the init script tries to launch every .conf file it finds in the /etc/openvpn directory while Gentoo uses soft links matching with them. Every .conf should have a different "daemon this.vpn.name" and a unique "port"

Comment: You can post a comment to request clarification on the OP system specification allowing you to give a more specific answer. I have posted a comment to the OP asking for this information.